# Simple Add method produces too much IL code

Tags: c#, cil

I'm trying to improve my C# math operations by using IL code. One problem is currently that C# does not allow math operations on generics, but the IL does - at least for the primitive data types (interestingly not decimal). For that reason I created some test method in C# to check that the resulting IL code.
Here's the code of the C# method:

```
  public static float Add(float A, float B)
  {
        return A + B;
  }
```

Here's the result VS2015SP2 / Release + Optimizations turned on.
Just to make sure: Here`s the csc command line from the build:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig
>   /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred
>   /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation
>   /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug- /filealign:512 /optimize+
>   /out:obj\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis
>   Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
>   /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output Program.cs
>   Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>   obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
>   obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
>   obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
>   (TaskId:27) 1>

```
    .method public hidebysig static 
    float32 Add (
        float32 A,
        float32 B
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2054
    // Code size 9 (0x9)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] float32
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: add
    IL_0004: stloc.0
    IL_0005: br.s IL_0007

    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: ret
} // end of method Program::Add
```

Do you know any reason why there is still nop in it, why there's a local variable and why there's a jump at the end that does nothing?

It's clear to me that the final jitter might solve this, but if I see this I don't know, if I can trust the jitter.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: nop comes because you build in debug configuration. If you want a cleaner IL you might build in release configuration.

Comment: Not really. As I wrote, Optimizations are turned on and I switched to release mode.

Comment: Branch opcode comes to make you able to have a breakpoint at the end of the method. Agin, because of debug configuration.

Comment: Understood. But there's nothing more I can do, but switch to release and check the "Optimize code" checkbox, Do you know how I can check that command line arguments of msbuild in the VS GUI output?

Comment: Yes I missed that you wrote you built in release config. But my experience says there is sth wrong with the build configuration. Would you check the project properties (not the combobox on toolbars) and make sure there is also configured as release?

Comment: Hi Abdullah. Yes you are right, this is what I have also read in some posts. I have added the csc command line. It seems that everything is ok: /debug- /optimize+

Comment: Yes, it seems it is in release configuration. From which directory did you get this dll file in order to disassemble it? Might you be building in release config but copying from bin\debug\ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I cannot repeat your results. Compiling with csc /debug- /optimize+ and then using ildasm, I get:

```
.method public hidebysig static float32  Add(float32 A,
                                             float32 B) cil managed
{
  // Code size       4 (0x4)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  add
  IL_0003:  ret
} // end of method Program::Add
```

which is what I'd expect from optimized code. Indeed if I change to optimize-, I get the code you posted. Are you checking a Debug vs. Release subdirectory perhaps?

Comment: This is exactly what I get. I get OPs code when disabling optimizations.

Comment: Hi Jesse and Rob. Sometimes it helps that someone shows me how stupid I am. You were absolutely right Jesse.